# Adding a query parameter in python for Bitbucket's API

Tags: python, api, bitbucket, query-string

I'm not sure where to implement the query parameter for `async` in this python code. I don't have a development background and to the extent that I write code as part of my job, it's not python.

The context is that I am using Zapier to automate our CI/CD and Zapier has a timeout of 10 seconds, which a bitbucket merge seemingly always exceeds. So, I need to force an immediate 202 response rather than wait. The [bitbucket api docs](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/bitbucket/rest/api-group-pullrequests/#api-repositories-workspace-repo-slug-pullrequests-pull-request-id-merge-post) state:

[image: Bitbucket API docs for merging pull requests with the async query parameter]

...but I'm not sure where to put that. My code is below, with `?q=async=true` added to the end of the URL. Prior to this addition, it's been tested as completely functional (minus the timeout issue). It's quite difficult to test this in Zapier outside of an in-flight deployment, so I wanted to run it past the community before trying.

```
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
import json


payload = json.dumps({"pullrequest_merge_parameters":
                      {"type": "merge",
                       "message": "Automated Merge to master on UAT validation",
                       "close_source_branch": "false",
                       "merge_strategy": ["merge_commit"]}
                      })

auth_string = HTTPBasicAuth("username", "password")
r = requests.post("https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/workspace/repo/pullrequests/" + input_data["pull_request_id"] + "/merge?q=async=true",
                  auth=auth_string,
                  headers={"Content-Type": "application/json"},
                  data=payload)
```

Comment: add it to the payload

Comment: @gold_cy What I don't understand is why the async parameter is under "Query Parameters" whereas everything else is under "Body Parameters" in the docs. What's the difference? So are you suggesting that I just add it as a pullrequest_merge_parameter, along with type, merge_strategy, etc?

Comment: it should be a top level key also I don't see the key `pullrequest_merge_parameters` mentioned in the link you provided